# HikariCP - Unknown Host Exception for AS400 Server

Tags: ibm-midrange, hikaricp

Below is my configuration within my POM.xml for my connection pool and datasource.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="poolName" value="springPool"/>
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="serverName">jdbc:as400://xxx.xxx.com;naming=system;prompt=false</prop>
                <prop key="user">xxxxx</prop>
                <prop key="password">xxxxx</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I'm receiving an UnknownHostException at the end of my stack trace, but here's what I'm seeing at the beginning of my stack trace:

```
Jul 23, 2019 9:46:15 AM com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource getConnection
INFO: springPool - Starting...
Jul 23, 2019 9:46:16 AM com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool 
throwPoolInitializationException
SEVERE: springPool - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the 
connection. (jdbc:as400://xxx.xxx.com;naming=system;prompt=false)
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:565)
at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the server name as follows:

```
  <prop key="serverName">xxx.xxx.com</prop>
```

Allowed my connection to complete. My Connection Pool is now started up and I can hit the AS400 Server.